# Vector spaces as free algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, universal-algebra

Exercise 4.6 of An algebraic introduction to mathematical logic asks: $K$ is a field. Show that vector spaces over $K$ form a variety $V$ of algebras, and that every space over $K$ is a free algebra of $V$.

They give the following definition for free algebra:

> a T-algebra $R$ in the variety $V$ is the free algebra of $V$ on the set $X$ of free generators (where a function $\sigma: X\to R$ is given, usually as an inclusion) if, for every algebra $A$ in $V$ and every function $t: X\to A$ there exists a unique homomorphism $p: R\to A$ such that $p\sigma = t$.

Given that definition, it doesn't seem to me that $K$ can be a free algebra of $V$, it has to be a free algebra of $V$ **on some set** $X$. Is that correct? If so, what set am I implicitly supposed to assume it is a free algebra on?

Comment: The exercise is badly worded: it should say every vector space $S$ over $K$ is a free algebra over $X$ *for some set $X$*. To prove this, given $S$ you can take $X$ to be any basis of $S$. (Moreover only a basis will do: $X$ has to be linearly independent to give existence of $p$ and a spanning set to give uniqueness of $p$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a basis $X$ for your vector space $R$. (For infinite-dimensional spaces you need the axiom of choice.) Here $\sigma:X \to R$ is the inclusion map. Then every function from $X$ to another vector space extends uniquely to a linear map.

Comment: I agree that this works, but wouldn't it also work for e.g. $X =\emptyset $? How am I supposed to know from the question what $X$ should be? Is $X$ supposed to be the free generators of $R$?

Comment: @Xodarap No, this won't work if $X$ isn't a basis, so $X = \emptyset$ won't work except if $R$ is trivial. To see why in this case, *any* linear map from $R$ to another nontrivial vector space $S$ extends the map $\emptyset \to S$, and unless $R = \{ 0 \}$ there is more than one linear map $R \to S$. So uniqueness fails to hold.

Comment: @Xodarap Yes, $X$ should be thought of a set of free generators for $R$. If we're dealing with free groups, free modules, vector spaces, free algebras, etc., it is clear what $X$ should be. More generally, look up free objects in category theory.